# T-SQL Query to Pull a Parent's Tags and all Children's Tags

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

## Backgroud

I have a DB Schema in SQL Server that looks like the following:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dc3cf/3

```
| id    | tag   | child_id  |
|----   |-----  |---------- |
| 1     | A     |           |
| 1     |       | 4         |
| 2     | C     |           |
| 3     | C     |           |
| 4     | B     |           |
| 4     |       | 5         |
| 5     | D     |           |
| 5     | E     |           |
```

Each 'id' record may have a child (which is stored in the same table). Each child may have any number of sub children. I won't know the number of hierarchy levels but it will probably be no more than 10 levels deep.

In the example, there are:

- 3 root elements: id's `1`, `2`, `3`
- 1 child and 1 child's child of id `1`: id's `4` and `5` (respectively)

## Question

I need to be able to query to get a result of all of an id's tags including all of it's children's tags. For example, I would need my output to be the following based on the table data above:

```
| id    | tag   |
|----   |-----  |
| 1     | A     |
| 1     | B     |
| 1     | D     |
| 1     | E     |
| 2     | C     |
| 3     | C     |
| 4     | B     |
| 5     | D     |
| 5     | E     |
```

Note that I need the children to still appear.

Is this possible without joining the table to itself 'n' many times where 'n' is the number of hierarchy levels?

### Edit

To clarify, each id is also a root elements. So the only way to know if an ID is also a child is to look and see if the id has another record where it has a child_id. I made another version of the SQL Fiddle that demonstrates this point. Note that id 2 now has a child:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/422f9/1

```
| id    | tag   | child_id  |
|----   |-----  |---------- |
| 1     | A     |           |
| 1     |       | 4         |
| 2     | C     |           |
| 2     |       | 5         |
| 3     | C     |           |
| 4     | B     |           |
| 4     |       | 5         |
| 5     | D     |           |
| 5     | E     |           |
```

Comment: SQL Server supports hierarchical queries using "Recursive Common Table Expressions", or "Recursive CTE".

Comment: Why 5 changed to 6 in resultset? Is that a requirement or typo?

Comment: @KannanKandasamy, Requirement typo, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Are the elements with an ID of `1` the root elements (because of the desired result example)? Or asked differently: Have ALL root elements an ID of `1`?

Comment: @R.Horber. The root elements in the above example are 1, 2 and 3. Not all root elements have an id of 1.

Comment: @Nxtq. I see, I hadn't enought patience :). I updated the query (again).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible without joining the table n-times, you can use a CTE (Common Table Expression), [see Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)

In your situation the code should be something like:

```
WITH cte (id, tag, child_id, parent) AS
(
    SELECT id, tag, child_id, id
    FROM demo
    WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT child_id FROM demo WHERE child_id IS NOT NULL)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT demo.id, demo.tag, demo.child_id, cte.parent
    FROM demo
        JOIN cte
            ON cte.child_id = demo.id
)
SELECT parent, tag
FROM cte
WHERE tag IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT id, tag
FROM demo
WHERE tag IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY parent, tag
```

**Edit**: Determine base elements dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution seems to error out on max recursion. Even setting the option for max recurrsion to 1000 doesn't seem to solve it. I loaded this example up into SQL fiddle to demonstrate: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dc3cf/2

Comment: You are right. I was not able to test it (as I have not a local SQL Server anymore). There's a logic error in my query which causes an infinite loop. I'm trying to fix it... I'll let you know

Comment: Thanks for the update again! I should clarify that I won't know what the id's are that are root elements. And sometimes an element is both a root element AND a child element. Based on your query do you think it would be a hard requirement to know which elements are roots?

Comment: Maybe there is a better alternative than an `IN`, which did not yet come to my mind or I'm not aware of. Fact is, that a recursive query has to start at some point (base/root elements). With `tag IS NULL` or `child_id IS NOT NULL` I didn't get your desired result or an infinite loop...

Comment: Third time was indeed the charm, thank you so much for sticking with me!

Comment: @Nxtq Tips: If you really do need more than 100 levels of recursion then use the [`maxrecursion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query?view=sql-server-2017) query hint to alter the limit. If your data might contain loops then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119057/sql-recursive-cte-finding-objects-linked-by-property/42139978#42139978) answer demonstrates a method for terminating the recursion gracefully.