# Join within same table to retrieve hierarchy (Parent-Child Hierarchy)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have two tables - **Master** and **Child**. Child table contains hierarchal data for MainId stored in Master table.

Master.Name is Unique

Master.MainId = Child.ChildId

Child.ParentId = Child.ChildId

I have to retrieve all data from Child table for Master.RelDate and Master.Name. I thought it was a straight forward query but somehow not able to pull desired output. I'm ending up with just one Child table record no matter how I write query.

Is it to do with table structure or my query?

**Note**: None of the ParentIds and ChildIds are in sequence. That data comes from another system, I just put those values for simplicity.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Master') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Master END
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Child') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP TABLE #Child END
GO
CREATE TABLE #Master
(
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RelDate DATE NOT NULL,
    MainId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
)
GO
CREATE TABLE #Child
(
    Id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1),
    RelDate DATE NOT NULL,
    ChildId BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ParentId BIGINT NULL,
    Label VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    Value VARCHAR(1024) NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #Master(RelDate,MainId,Name) VALUES ('2019-01-01',1,'Name1')
INSERT INTO #Master(RelDate,MainId,Name) VALUES ('2019-01-01',11,'Name11')
GO
INSERT INTO #Child(RelDate,ChildId,ParentId,Label,Value) VALUES
('2019-01-01',1,2,'Level10',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',2,3,'Level09',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',3,4,'Level08',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',4,5,'Level07',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',5,6,'Level06','This is level 6')
,('2019-01-01',6,7,'Level05',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',7,8,'Level04',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',8,9,'Level03','This is level 3')
,('2019-01-01',9,10,'Level02',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',10,11,'Level01',NULL) -- Always same
,('2019-01-01',11,NULL,'Root',NULL) -- Always same

INSERT INTO #Child(RelDate,ChildId,ParentId,Label,Value) VALUES
('2019-01-01',11,12,'Level10',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',12,13,'Level09',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',13,14,'Level08',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',14,15,'Level07',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',15,16,'Level06','This is level 6')
,('2019-01-01',16,17,'Level05',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',17,18,'Level04',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',18,19,'Level03','This is level 3')
,('2019-01-01',19,10,'Level02',NULL)
,('2019-01-01',10,11,'Level01',NULL) -- Always same
,('2019-01-01',11,NULL,'Root',NULL) -- Always same
GO

SELECT * FROM #Master
SELECT * FROM #Child
```

**Desired output** for RelDate = 2019-01-01 and Name = Name1

```
SELECT chld.*
FROM #Master mst (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN #Child chld (NOLOCK) ON (mst.MainId = chld.ChildId)
    LEFT JOIN #Child chld1 (NOLOCK) ON (chld.ParentId = chld.ChildId)
WHERE mst.RelDate = '2019-01-01' -- Input 1
AND mst.Name = 'Name1' -- Input 2
```

All the data from Child table

```
Id  RelDate ChildId ParentId    Label   Value
1   2019-01-01  1   2   Level10 NULL
2   2019-01-01  2   3   Level09 NULL
3   2019-01-01  3   4   Level08 NULL
4   2019-01-01  4   5   Level07 NULL
5   2019-01-01  5   6   Level06 This is level 6
6   2019-01-01  6   7   Level05 NULL
7   2019-01-01  7   8   Level04 NULL
8   2019-01-01  8   9   Level03 This is level 3
9   2019-01-01  9   10  Level02 NULL
10  2019-01-01  10  11  Level01 NULL
11  2019-01-01  11  NULL    Root    NULL
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your desired output

Comment: Included output in the question

Comment: You need a recursive CTE for this, and also remove your loops in your data (10 to 19, 19 to 18... back to 10, then 10 to 19 again makes an infinite loop).

Comment: @EzLo that's how the data is. Those Ids are from other system, no control over that. Do you have CTE example?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42119057/sql-recursive-cte-finding-objects-linked-by-property/42139978#42139978) answer demonstrates a method for handling loops in data by keeping track of the rows already processed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.* from #Child c inner join #Master M
on M.MainId = C.ChildId

Id  RelDate ChildId ParentId    Label   Value
1   2019-01-01  1   2   Level10 NULL
11  2019-01-01  11  NULL    Root    NULL
```

If this isn't the desired output, please provide your desired output.

Comment: You missed input parameters

Comment: Included output in the question

Answer (score 0):

It seams that data in the tables is kinda non logical. Especially with the 'Name11'. I assume that with every new rows you will lose one id from Childid column .Now we lose 'lvl2' at row 19.
I tried to figure out some solution, now my position here.
It works for 'Name1', but result for 'Name11' a bit different.

```
SELECT   t2.* 
FROM #Master mst 
      join  #Child t1 ON mst.MainId = t1.ChildId
           join  #Child t2 ON t2.parentid >= t1.ChildId  

WHERE mst.RelDate = '2019-01-01' -- Input 1
AND mst.Name = 'Name1'           -- Input 2

order by t2.id 
offset 0 rows 
fetch first 10 rows only
```

Maybe it helps you a little. I will try to find a tricky solution.

Comment: thanks for your input. I think I should have mentioned that none on ParentId and ChildId are in sequence. That data comes from another system, I just put those values for simplicity.

Comment: Can't edit comments for some reason. ParentId and ChildId are NOT in sequence