# Find isolated group in the linked data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of friends. Two columns: friend1 and friend2  containing ids of the friends with possible cycles
The following data

```
(1,2) 
(2,1) 
(1,3) 
(4,5) 
(5,4)
```

means that `1,2,3` is one group and `4` and `5` are another group

I need to find all groups and list their members.
I have tried with recursive CTE, but the cyclicity of the graph is a problem.
Any idea?

Comment: Could you identify the cyclic ones beforehand and exclude one of them?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42139978/92546) answer demonstrates a way to terminate recursion when there are cycles in the data by tracking the path for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive cte, but I guess you will have to break the cyclicity. Following a rough approach to it - on first glance it looked as expected, but you will have to modify it e.g. if you want to pivot the friends per group or whatever:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(ID int, FriendID int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (1,2), (2,1), (1,3), (2,3), (4,5), (5,4)

;WITH cteDist AS(
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN ID > FriendID THEN FriendID ELSE ID END AS ID,  CASE WHEN ID > FriendID THEN ID ELSE FriendID END AS FriendID
  FROM @t
),
cteTop AS(
SELECT DISTINCT i.ID
  FROM cteDist i
  LEFT JOIN cteDist f ON f.FriendID = i.ID
  WHERE f.ID IS NULL
),
cteGroups AS(
SELECT ID, ID AS FriendID
  FROM cteTop
UNION ALL
SELECT c.ID, f.FriendID
  FROM cteGroups c
  INNER JOIN cteDist f ON f.ID = c.FriendID
)
SELECT DISTINCT ID, FriendID
  FROM cteGroups
  ORDER BY 1, 2
  OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```